# spark-submit classNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark, classnotfoundexception

I'm building a spark app with maven (with shade plugin) and scp'ing it to a data node for execution with spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster (since launching right from the build system with --deploy-mode client doesn't work because of asymmetric network not under my control).

Here's my launch command

> spark-submit 
>           --class Test 
>           --master yarn 
>           --deploy-mode cluster 
>           --supervise 
>           --verbose 
>           jarName.jar 
>           hdfs:///somePath/Test.txt 
>           hdfs:///somePath/Test.out

The job quickly fails with a ClassNotFoundException for Test$1; one of the anonymous classes java creates from my main class

> 6/03/18 12:59:41 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage
>   0.0 (TID 0, dataNode3): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test$1

I've seen this error mentioned many times (google) and most recommendations boil down to calling conf.setJars(jarPaths) or similar.

I really don't see why this is needed when the missing class is definitely (I've checked) available in jarName.jar , why specifying this at compile time is preferable to doing it  at run time with --jar as a spark-submit argument, and in either case, what path I should provide for the jar. I've been copying it to my home directory on the datanode from target/jarName.jar on the build system but it seems spark-submit copies it to hdfs somewhere that's hard to nail down into a hard-coded path name at either compile time or launch time.

And most of all, why isn't spark-submit handling this automatically based on the someJar.jar argument, and if not, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Just tried using --deployMode client on a lark and it worked! I really don't understand this.

Comment: I believe that Spark can not find your jar. Is your jar present in each node? Did you try to specify absolute path to the jar?

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer from here 
[spark submit java.lang.ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983708/spark-submit-java-lang-classnotfoundexception)

```
spark-submit --class Test --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --supervise --verbose jarName.jar hdfs:///somePath/Test.txt hdfs:///somePath/Test.out
```

Try to use, also you could check the absolute path in your project

```
--class com.myclass.Test
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Scala Spark application when I tried to run it in "cluster" mode:

```
--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster
```

I found the solution on [this](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/207442243-Spark-submit-fails-with-class-not-found-when-deploying-in-cluster-mode) page. Basically what I was missing (that is missing also in your command) is the "--jars" parameter that allows you to distribute the application jars to your cluster.

**Suggestion**: to be able to troubleshooting this kind of error you could use the following command:

```
yarn logs --applicationId yourApplicationId
```

where *yourApplicationId* shoould be in your yarn exception log.