# Spark-JobServer Java Client - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spark-jobserver

I am using the Spark JobServer Java Client from this GitHub project:

https://github.com/bluebreezecf/SparkJobServerClient

I am able to upload a Jar containing the Job I want to execute to Spark JobServer. The logs indicate it is stored in /tmp/spark-jobserver directory structure.  However, when accessing it from the context I create, the Job class if not found, so the Jar is not being loaded for my Job request.

**EDIT**:  I later discovered that the jar that is uploaded by the Java Client is corrupt.  That is why Spark JobServer cannot use it.  When I manually replaced it with a good Jar the JobServer ran it fine.  Now, the real problem is related to the client's uploadSparkJobJar() API.

> org.khaleesi.carfield.tools.sparkjobserver.api.SparkJobServerClientException:
>   Spark Job Server http://sparkjobserverhost:8090/ response 404 {   "status":
>   "ERROR",   "result": "classPath org.kritek.scalability.jobs.Olap1 not
>   found" }

Here is my code:

```
        //POST /contexts/<name>--Create context with parameters
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(ISparkJobServerClientConstants.PARAM_MEM_PER_NODE, "512m");
        params.put(ISparkJobServerClientConstants.PARAM_NUM_CPU_CORES, "10");
        params.put("dependent-jar-uris", "file:///tmp/spark-jobserver/filedao/data/olap1_job-2016-08-11T04_47_07.802Z.jar");
        boolean success = client.createContext(contextName, params);

        assertTrue(success);

        //dependent-jar-uris=file:///some/path/of/my-foo-lib.jar

        //Post /jobs---Create a new job 
        params.put(ISparkJobServerClientConstants.PARAM_APP_NAME, appName);
        params.put(ISparkJobServerClientConstants.PARAM_CLASS_PATH, "org.kritek.scalability.jobs.Olap1");

        SparkJobResult result = null;
        String jobId = null;

        params.put(ISparkJobServerClientConstants.PARAM_CONTEXT, contextName);
        params.put(ISparkJobServerClientConstants.PARAM_SYNC, "true");
        result = client.startJob("conf-1=1", params);
```

Comment: Can you try using curl command so that we can isolate the issue?

Comment: So the problem is with the client. Can you file an issue on GitHub project SparkJobServerClient ?

Comment: https://github.com/bluebreezecf/SparkJobServerClient/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer from here 
[spark submit java.lang.ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983708/spark-submit-java-lang-classnotfoundexception)

Note: if you are used maven project you could use mvn package assembly:single to include your dependecies.

```
spark-submit --class Test --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --supervise --verbose jarName.jar hdfs:///somePath/Test.txt hdfs:///somePath/Test.out
```

Try to use, also you could check the absolute path in your project

```
--class com.myclass.Test
```